# Keras metrics during model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Are these metrics, displayed while `model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=128)` is running

```
945792/1424460 [==================>...........] - ETA: 5:22 - loss: 0.7029 - accuracy: 0.7312
945920/1424460 [==================>...........] - ETA: 5:22 - loss: 0.7029 - accuracy: 0.7312
946048/1424460 [==================>...........] - ETA: 5:22 - loss: 0.7029 - accuracy: 0.7312
```

an information about

- the average loss on the current mini batch? (i.e. on the last 128 training inputs)
- the average loss since the beginning of the epoch?
- the average loss since the beginning of all epochs, i.e. the start of the training process?

The same question applies to the accuracy: on what is it computed exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The average loss since the beginning of the epoch.

In general it's like (this is pseudocode):

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    total_batches = 0
    total_loss = 0

    for batch in range(batches):
        total_loss += calculate_loss(batch)
        total_batches += 1

        displayed_loss = total_loss / total_batches
```

The same goes for every metric. But again, metrics may be written as the user likes it. Usually they're an average of the batch.

For each batch: get the batch loss as calculated (most of them are an average of samples, but losses may return whatever you code)

---

When the loss is evolving (it's not evolving in your example, it's frozen), you will notice a significant difference between the loss displayed for the last epoch and the initial loss of the current epoch. This difference is because the previus loss was considering also the initial batches in a time when the model wasn't as well trained.